# esacpe key exits full screen mode java

Tags: java, fullscreen

I have build a game in Java in full screen mode, I use this code to go full screen:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)screenSize.getWidth(), (int)screenSize.getHeight()));
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        if(gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Full screen not supported!!");
            
        }
```

On some windows systems when I press the ESCAPE key the program will exit fullscreen mode and minimize. How do I block this "function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, when I switch views, the program loses focus, so windows will handle the ESCAPE key event. I solved it by requesting the focus every time the view changes.

like this:

```
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                View.this.requestFocusInWindow();
            }            
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own key listener, and handle your keypress, the way you want to. You could look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

EDIT: [this](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/post1.0/ui/keylistener.html) seems to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

If this is using Swing then you should be using [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Swing was designed to use KeyBindings, not KeyEvents.

Comment: I have already tried using KeyBindings AND keyListeners to consume the escape key event, but is has no effect.